# Store all users info on login

Tags: php

Is it best to store all the users information in session cookies like this on login? Instead of using alot of querys

```
$_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
$_SESSION['name'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'name');
$_SESSION['email'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'email');
$_SESSION['ip'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'regip');
$_SESSION['groupid'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'group_id');
$_SESSION['style'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'style');
```

Or maybe just store ID in session then query on all page:

```
select * from users where id = $_SESSION['id']
```

Comment: Also might want to look into memcache, then you can store in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be using them a lot, sure. Although I'd be careful about storing *all* of the users data in the Session. Only what is necessary. Keep in mind that well-written queries are cheap on resources. Don't try to avoid connecting to the database altogether, just be sure that when you do it, you do it well.

You can test your memory-consumption if you like using `memory_get_usage()`. But note that session data is stored in a flat file on the system itself:

```
session_start();
echo memory_get_usage(); // 87744
$_SESSION["user"] = array(
    "name"    => "Jonathan Sampson",
    "id"      => 54680,
    "groupID" => 0285,
    "email"   => "example@somesite.com",
    "style"   => "background-color:#333;color:#f1f1f1"
);
echo memory_get_usage(); // 88344
```

So you can see that it's really very trivial to store this amount of data.

**See also:** [Cache data in PHP SESSION, or query from db each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387587/cache-data-in-php-session-or-query-from-db-each-time)

Comment: I agree. I usually just save the `UserID`, and use that (+ other environmental variables) to get the user's details from the database.

Comment: +1: In my opinion, the only information that should be a candidate for sessions is that which is required for every single page.  Otherwise, go back to the database as needed.

Comment: But what if the user changes their email address? The developer has to remember to amend the session var. If you only save the user id but fetch the rest from the db each time, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Exactly adam. If you are providing your users the ability to change the data, then you probably shouldn't store it in session.

Comment: I been caching like 10 values for each user in file based session, I didn't realize it was not good, it seems like such a small amount of data.  Maybe I should re-think this

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a (salted) hash for each user, saved in the db:

```
$salt = 'asdjnvdskflds';
$hash = md5($salt . $email);
```

Then store the hash in the session. That way, you can call the user data each time. This also has the benefit of not having to update the session if the user changes some of his/her data.